# Compile on save not working on NetBeans 14, 15

Tags: netbeans

I have checked a lot of messages and the different solutions where people get issues on Netbeans that is not compiling on save.

I was previously working with Netbeans 12 and this was working fine : compile was done on save.

But recently I have updated to Netbeans 14 and now 15 and compile on save is not working anymore. I cannot pinpoint where is the issue and how to solve it.

For the moment I have set :

1 - In Netbeans "Options" : Tab Java -> Java Debugger : I activated "Apply code changes after save (in "Compile on Save" mode only)
2 - In project properties : Build -> Compiling : I deactivated "Compile on Save"

Then when a modification is made and when I save I see in front of the file I have modified a small wrench and then I have to hit F9 to manually compile and then the wrench is gone.

I have tried all combinaisons of those 2 options but only this one is close to the old "Compile on save".

Am I the only one with that issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So your method worked but with a slight difference, i did NOT deactivate "Compile on Save" - Everything works fine now.